# Should I include large tables in paper?

Tags: publications, writing-style, software-papers

I am writing a computer science paper, and as part of what I did, I have a set of tests I used to evaluate my results against existing methods.

In terms of preliminary raw data, I have tables of hundreds of values of which I then take statistical parameters (e.g. mean and standard deviation).

From a scientific perspective I feel I should include the actual results that I got, such that if I forget something in my writeup, e.g. the mode, other researchers can look at my data and corroborate or criticize my results. Basically it seems good form to have all the data in the paper.

But if I do include the raw results I will get a good couple of pages that are nothing but numbers on a table. Which seems bloated for an article and I suspect reviewers won't like it I am not sure how I should handle this.

Comment: Supplemental CSV file. Boom. Done.

Comment: How do I distribute the CSV? Do I post it on github and provide a link in the paper and call it a day?

Comment: Submit it as supplemental material with your paper and let the journal deal with it

Comment: @Libor I think you should post your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talk to your editor. Their job is to help you disseminate supplemental information, while keeping paper to style and readable.

As Libor mentions in comments, modern journals accept wide range of supplemental materials, and either will host the files (CSV) or suggest the ways to deposit it

Answer (score 1):

No.  Hundreds of values is too many for a table in a PDF document.  Imagine the frustration of someone trying to convert those numbers to a spreadsheet.

Depending on the situation, you might choose to present the values as:

- A plot
- A table in a CSV file
- A database

Any of which could be published by the journal or a repository.

In some cases summary statistics like mean are sufficient.

Comment: Providing "hundreds" of values in a database format (e.g. SQLite) seems like overkill ... ?